# NetBeans: data shows in app window but not in table output window

Tags: java, database, jdbc, netbeans

I have an issue with my database application. When I launch the application I input some data and click the add button. The application window pops up and shows the data in the table.

However, when I go to the **Services** tab in NetBeans and right click on the table and select 'View Data' I see nothing but blank rows in the table output window.

Any ideas why this is happening? Here is a screenshot of the problem:

[image: App and View Data Windows]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Community There is no relevant code to show. The question is about two different tools within NetBeans giving conflicting results. How would providing code be meaningful in any way?